# XPath code to obtain class text within another class?

Tags: html, python-3.x, dom, xpath, scrapy

Snippet of HTML code via inspect page:

```html
<div class="wBox"> 
  <ul class="detailListHorizontal" id="firstBoxHeight">
    <li class="">
       <label class="">Category</label>
       <a href="https://www.boat24.com/en/powerboats/" title="Power Boats" class="">Power Boats</a>
    <li class="">
    <li class="">
       <label class="">Boat Type</label>
       <a href="https://www.boat24.com/en/powerboats/center-console-boat/?typ=2119" title="Center console boat" class="">Center console boat</a>
    <li class="">
```

What I need scraped `Power Boats` and `Center console boat` strings.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
response.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Category')]/following-sibling::text()").extract() = empty list
response.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Category')]/a/text()").extract() = empty list
response.xpath("//label[contains(.,'Category')]/text()").extract() = returns 'Category'
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are there other sibilings `<li>` tags that you don't want to select? Or there is only those 2?

Comment: Yes, there are many other sibling `<li>` classes which I don't want selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//label[. = 'Category' or . = 'Boat Type']/following-sibling::a/text()
```

will select the text of those `a` elements following `labels` with string values of
`'Category'` or `'Boat Type'`,

```
Power Boats
Center console boat
```

as requested.

If the `label` elements have whitespace variations, replace the `. =` with `normalize-space() =`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.